# Url.Action returns wrong value .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, razor, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Razor view, .Net Core 3.1 project

This code

```
var action = Url.Action("AccsResults", new
{
    ProducersIds = Model.ProducersIds,
    Article = Model.Article,
    Name = Model.Name,
    ItemsPerPage = Model.ItemsPerPage,
    categories = categories,
    SortBy = Model.SortBy,
    OnlySale = Model.OnlySale,
    Hit = Model.Hit
});
```

returns:

> /Catalog/AccsResults/categories-9169601?ItemsPerPage=50&SortBy=NameAsc&OnlySale=False&Hit=False

But, if **page parameter added** to list

```
var action = Url.Action("AccsResults", new
{
    Page = 1,
    ProducersIds = Model.ProducersIds,
    Article = Model.Article,
    Name = Model.Name,
    ItemsPerPage = Model.ItemsPerPage,
    categories = categories,
    SortBy = Model.SortBy,
    OnlySale = Model.OnlySale,
    Hit = Model.Hit
});
```

it returns:

> "/Catalog/AccsResults?Page=1&ItemsPerPage=50&SortBy=NameAsc&OnlySale=False&Hit=False"

**/categories-916960 is lost.** Only page parameter makes it wrong.

Why it happens? How can i get variant 1 whith page parameter in list?

*upd: Routes configuration*

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "default",
  template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Comment: How are the routes configured?

Comment: It's interesting that in the first example it appears that it's treating `categories` as part of the route but not in the second. I'd guess there is something going on there that is causing this but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Can you show us your model structure and the model data you use here?